# How to wait synchronously on cancellation of async task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have a generic class which runs certain work packages asynchronously. It has the possibility to cancel the execution of all tasks and wait synchronously on the completion of the canceled tasks. The cancellation is triggered before a new transaction (the user does something) starts. This is necessary because the asynchronous task as well as the new transaction would change the same objects, but the asynchronous task would do it while assuming the state before the transaction.

Here a sample code why this behavior is so important:

```
private void Transaction()
{
    asyncExecution.AbortAllAsyncWork();
    DoTransaction();
}
```

This method is called synchronously and DoTransaction changes objects which are also changed in the asynchronous tasks. For example list could be changed while they are iterated.

Previously I achieved this behavior with the ContinueWith method on tasks where I passed a synchronous task scheduler. All in all it was hard to understand and seemed kind of dirty. Therefore I wondered if I could achieve the same behavior with the new async-await feature. The problem here lies in a deadlock described [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). The code so far with the deadlock problem:

```
public void RunAsync<TWork, TResult>(IIncrementalAsyncExecutable<TWork, TResult> executable, TWork initialWork) where TWork : class
{
    Task workingTask = RunAsyncInternal(executable, initialWork, CancellationTokenSource);
    if (IsRunning(workingTask))
    {
        workingTasks.Add(workingTask);
    }
}

private async Task RunAsyncInternal<TWork, TResult>(IIncrementalAsyncExecutable<TWork, TResult> executable, TWork initialWork, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource) where TWork : class
{
    while (!executable.WorkDone)
    {
        TResult result = await Task.Run(() => executable.CalculateNextStep(initialWork));
        executable.SyncResult(result);
        if (tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}

public void AbortAllAsyncWork()
{
    CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    foreach (Task workingTask in workingTasks)
    {
        if (IsRunning(workingTask))
        {
            workingTask.Wait(); // here is the deadlock problem
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a possibility to achieve this behavior with the new async-await feature without deadlock?

Comment: On a side note, why do you need the `while` loop in `RunAsyncInternal`?

Comment: Work is scheduled in potions and these potions are synced back to the UI as soon as they finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a generic class which runs certain work packages asynchronously.

It's really much easier to use built-in types for this, like TPL Dataflow. They've done all the hard work.

> The problem is, that the application is designed synchronously.

Yes, but note that the problem is in the application's design. Waiting for tasks to complete is an inherently asynchronous operation, and the *best* solution is definitely [Yuval's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28580176/263693).

> Previously I achieved this behavior with the ContinueWith method on tasks where I passed a synchronous task scheduler.

I don't see how that could possibly avoid the deadlock you're seeing.

> I want to find a solution, where there is no refactoring necessary.

What you're really asking is "how do I do sync-over-async". The [best answer is "don't"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28580176/263693). But there are a few hacks that you can use to force it to work **in some scenarios**. There **is no general-purpose solution that always works**.

These hacks are: just block, push the operations onto a background thread, and run a nested message loop. They're described in more detail on [Stephen Toub's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx).

Comment: Ok I think in this case my hack must work for now. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If each `Task` is going to be cancelled, you can simply `await` on them and catch the `OperationCanceledException`:

```
public async Task AbortAllAsyncWork()
{
    CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    foreach (Task workingTask in workingTasks.Keys)
    {
        if (IsRunning(workingTask))
        {
            try
            {
                await workingTask;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
            {
                // Do something usefull
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or, you could simply `await Task.WhenAll` on all the tasks:

```
await Task.WhenAll(workingTasks.Keys)
```

Assuming `Keys` is an `IEnumerable<Task>`, the returned `Task` would be in a `Canceled` state.

Comment: This would mean when I call AbortAllAsyncWork, that the method returns before all threads have finished there work, would it not?

Comment: @Yggdrasil Yes, it will yield control higher up the callstack. Why is that a problem? It doesn't "complete", it simply asynchronously waits for all tasks to be canceled.

Comment: @Yggdrasil What is that? a constructor? a private method?

Comment: Please see my edits at the main questions. it was not possible to show it in a comment.

Comment: @Yggdrasil Don't run this from `private void`, run it from `private async Task` so you can `await`.

Comment: The problem is, that the application is designed synchronously. I would need to do this to at least hundreds of methods which in the end lead to a call of Transaction(). I want to find a solution, where there is no refactoring necessary.

Comment: Async is all the way. You're either synchronous or asynchronous.

Comment: I feared something like this. But you can not write a whole application new, which has grown for about five years only because at one point you want to have asynchronous behavior. Therefore I am looking for a trick which combines both worlds. I have done it previously, but it does not look very nice.